# Serve script via proxy server

Tags: javascript, proxy

I am setting up a website and need to load a script that is hosted on another server. I just want to hide the origin server.

```
<div><script src="https://ORIGIN-SERVER-URL.js" id="hidden_embed_calendar" data-env="https://www.hidden.com" data-version="v0.3" data-uid="934582" data-uuid="79681090" data-color="33ae3f" data-text="Book Now" data-title="Select Departure Date"></script></div>
```

I want my website users not be able to see the server this originally comes from. Is it possible to set up my own server between my website and the origin server as a proxy and server the script from my server? That would result in a source code of my website showing something like:

```
<div><script src="https://MY-SERVER.js" id="myserver_embed_calendar" data-env="https://www.myserver.com" data-version="v0.3" data-uid="934582" data-uuid="79681090" data-color="33ae3f" data-text="Book Now" data-title="Select Departure Date"></script></div>
```

What do I need to to to arrange this? Please advise me on the term I should be looking for.

I tried to google but could not find it. I do not know the search terms I need to find the answer. Am i looking for example for a javascript proxy server?